# Symfony Using gloabal parameters (from other Enity) in Entity

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, doctrine, entity

I need to use some global parameter on my Entity-Class (will be used during caluculation, while using a SETTER-function on an object).

Normally I would use CONST to set a class parameter.

But unfortunalley this parameter is only "semi"-constant, as it comes from an "option-table" of the database (so also an Entity).

### Problem

As I cannot use autowiring in the Entity, I am not able to use the `EntityManagerInterface`.
So I am not able to access the option-table.

### Question

What would be the best concept to follow to solve this issue?

Comment: suggest to use a service for this and not trying to mix business logic into entity classes